# musixtex error when using \ds

Tags: errors, musixtex

I'm trying to type the eighth rest with the package `musixtex`, but when I use the `\ds` command I get an error message. How could I right it?

```
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        \hline 

        \textbf{Nota} & \textbf{Nomenclatura} & \textbf{Pausa} & \textbf{Duração} \\ 

        \hline 

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\wh{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semibreve} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \liftpause} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1} \\ 

        \hline 

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\hu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Mínima} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \lifthpause} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/2} \\ 

        \hline 

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\qu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semínima} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \qp} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/4} \\

        \hline 

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\cu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Colcheia} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \ds} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/8} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\ccu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semicolcheia} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \qs} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/16} \\

        \hline 

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\cccu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Fusa} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \hs} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/32} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\ccccu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semifusa} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \qqs} & \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/64} \\

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really have posted a complete MWE, otherwise we don't know exactly what packages you loaded and in what order.

Just adding the minimum to get your snippet to run, I get several errors from `MusixTeX` before the "`\ds` not found" problem.

1. `\liftpause` and `\lifthpause` need an argument to say how much to move the rests up or down. But that doesn't work for a different reason - "you can't use `\raise` in internal vertical mode". Alternatively, just use `\pause` and `\hp`, but that doesn't show a short staff line with the rest above or below it.

   Since you didn't complain about that error, I haven't done any more than get LaTeX to continue past it. I guess you really need to put the rests on a one-line staff, or something like that.
2. In all the lines of the table, you forgot `\begin{music}...\end{music}` around the notation for the rests. Without that, I don't understand how *anything* in your snippet ever worked.
3. And finally, the "`\ds` not defined" problem you actually complained about!

   This seems to be a bug. It looks to me as if `musixTeX` was originally written in TeX not LaTeX, and then a wrapper to package it for LaTeX was added. It doesn't work in LaTeX because it attempts to alias the `\ds` macro to an internal macro, *before* the internal macro has been defined. A workround is to repeat the alias in the preamble of your document, *after* everything else has been set up by `musixTeX`. (The *real* fix would be to make the package do things in the right order, of course.)

Here's some code that works, though there are few problems with overfull boxes, etc.

Note: your repetitive use of `\parbox ... \centering \vspace ...` could be tidied up by putting the repetitive code into the column definitions after `\begin(tabular)`. Read the documentation or a tutorial for `tabular`. I didn't bother to tidy that up for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\makeatletter
\let\ds\ds@oup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        \hline

        \textbf{Nota} & \textbf{Nomenclatura} & \textbf{Pausa} & \textbf{Duração} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\wh{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semibreve} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \begin{music}\pause\end{music}} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\hu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Mínima} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \begin{music}\hp\end{music}} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/2} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\qu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semínima} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \begin{music}\qp\end{music}} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/4} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\cu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Colcheia} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \begin{music}\ds\end{music}} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/8} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\ccu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semicolcheia} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \begin{music}\qs\end{music}} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/16} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\cccu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Fusa} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \begin{music}\hs\end{music}} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/32} \\

        \hline

        \parbox[c][2cm]{0cm}{\centering\begin{music}\ccccu{p}\end{music}}\vspace{-.75cm} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} Semifusa} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} \begin{music}\qqs\end{music}} &
        \parbox[c][-1cm]{2cm}{\centering\vspace{-.75cm} 1/64} \\

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I think `musicTeX` is pretty much obsolete now, since there are much simpler free and open source applications that can do the job - for example Lilypond-book. That might account for why nobody has ever reported, or fixed, the `\ds` bug in LaTeX! On the other hand, the version in TeXLive 2017 was updated on 8 April 2017, so maybe this is a new bug ... I don't know.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! It sure fixed the issue I was having and I really appreciated your point about tiding up the tabular.

Comment: It's not really a bug; \ds is intended to be used in music and not in tables.  And while musictex is obsolete, musixtex isn't and is being actively used.  Check out the Werner Icking memorial web site.

Comment: Werner Icking memorial web site: http://icking-music-archive.org/software/htdocs